# Website background images flicker on Firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, flicker

We have a website whose background is a stack of images through which we go with JavaScript.

We check whether the next image is loaded before switching to it, and it works fine on Chrome, Safari, IE, and all mobile browsers, however on Firefox we sometimes get a white flash.

This problem also happens if we make sure that all the images are preloaded so it's not a problem that FF shows the image before it has finished loading. I've seen the question asked elsewhere but from the user's perspective, and the solution was to disable hardware graphics acceleration, which does not solve completely the problem but reduces it. However we obviously can't ask that from our users.

Similar problems were reported in other questions:

- [jquery animate (height) causes background-image flickering in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183508/jquery-animate-height-causes-background-image-flickering-in-firefox)
- [Image Flickering only in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438443/image-flickering-only-in-firefox)
- [Firefox background image flickering when using multiple instances and background-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873832/firefox-background-image-flickering-when-using-multiple-instances-and-background)
- [skrollr background image flicker in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543320/skrollr-background-image-flicker-in-firefox)

However none has a clear solution. Does anyone know how to correct for this?

Cheers!

Comment: It may be that you just want to turn off smoothing http://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16417178705/how-to-disable-image-smoothing-in-modern-web

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I learned something with that. However it does not correct the behavior we're having with the white flashes

Comment: The problem is fairly common, but it's cause can be for various reasons.  In order to diagnose the issue, can you provide a link?

Comment: you can check it at http://electrosanne.teleport.ninja

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing any flicker on Firefox on Mac.